# Pandas - replace all NaN values in DataFrame with empty python dict objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where each cell contains a python dict.

```
>>> data = {'Q':{'X':{2:2010}, 'Y':{2:2011, 3:2009}},'R':{'X':{1:2013}}}
>>> frame = DataFrame(data)
>>> frame
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}        NaN
```

I'd like to replace the NaN with an empty dict, to get this result:

```
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}        {}
```

However, because the `fillna` function interprets empty dict not as a scalar value but as a mapping of column --> value, it does NOTHING if I simply do this  (i.e. it doesn't work):

```
>>> frame.fillna(inplace=True, value={})
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}        NaN
```

Is there any way to use `fillna` to accomplish what I want?
Do I have to iterate through the entire DataFrame or construct a silly dict with all my columns mapped to empty dict?

Comment: The "silly solution" won't even work, since it'll then try to use *that* dict to figure out which values to use within each column's Series. At which point you need to write out the index of every value. So no, it's not workable, unfortunately. Just use loc as described below.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield Don't give up yet! You can create a dict within a dict to make it work. See my solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that storing nonscalar entries in cells isn't really supported, and a lot of pandas functionality will break.  YMMV, of course.

Comment: @DSM, doesn't numpy support Python objects in cells? I was under the impression pandas is based on numpy and supports any data type as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to use `DataFrame.applymap` in this way:

```
>>> from pandas import isnull
>>> frame=frame.applymap(lambda x: {} if isnull(x) else x)
>>> frame
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}         {}
```

This solution avoids the pitfalls in both EdChum's solution (where all NaN cells wind up pointing at same underlying dict object in memory, preventing them from being updated independently from one another) and Shashank's (where a potentially large data structure needs to be constructed with nested dicts, just to specify a single empty dict value).

Answer (score 6):

[`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) is a way of achieving this quite directly:

```
>>> data = {'Q': {'X': {2: 2010}, 'Y': {2: 2011, 3: 2009}}, 'R': {'X': {1: 2013}}}
>>> frame = DataFrame(data)
>>> frame
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}        NaN

>>> frame.where(frame.notna(), lambda x: [{}])
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}         {}
```

Also, it appears to be a bit faster:

```
>>> %timeit frame.where(frame.notna(), lambda x: [{}])
791 µs ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit frame.applymap(lambda x: {} if isnull(x) else x)
1.07 ms ± 7.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

(on larger datasets I've observed speedups of ~10x)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when a dict is passed to `fillna`, it tries to fill the values based on the columns in the frame. So the first solution I tried was -

```
frame.fillna({column: {} for column in frame.columns})
```

But if a dictionary is provided at the second level like this, it tries to match the keys against the index, so the solution that worked was -

```
frame.fillna({column: {ind: {} for ind in frame.index} for column in frame.columns})
```

Which gives -

```
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}         {}
```

EdChum's answer is probably better for your needs, but this can be used when you don't want to make changes in place.

EDIT: The solution above works well for smaller frames, but can be a problem for larger frames. Using `replace` can solve that.

```
frame.replace(np.nan, {column: {} for column in frame.columns})
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but the reason I called it the "silly" solution in my original question is that it seems wasteful to construct a large data structure (my DataFrame isn't really 2x2, as you can imagine) full of empty dicts.  Especially since python dicts are a bit memory hungry.

Comment: @ValAyal Agreed, it's a bit silly. For smaller frames it works, but for larger frames, this can be an issue. However, we can use `replace`! See edited answer.

Comment: using frame.replace has a similar problem as EdChum's answer with frame.loc.  All the NaNs in a particular column wind up pointing to the same dict object in memory, so they can't be independently changed.  I was finally able to accomplish what I was looking for using frame.applymap (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use `.values` accessor to assign into numpy array directly:

```
frame.R = frame.R.astype(object)  # assertion

frame.R.values[frame.R.isnull()] = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works using `loc`:

```
In [6]:

frame.loc[frame['R'].isnull(), 'R'] = {}
frame
Out[6]:
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}         {}
```

Comment: @acushner Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by all? This sets just the null 'R' values to an empty dict

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to delete. won't they all be the same empty dict? in other words, if you modify one later, it changes them all.

Comment: @acushner how do you figure that? Are you saying if I had multiple `NaN`'s updated them all to empty dicts, then modified just one row you're expecting all empty dicts to update?

Comment: it's all the same empty dict. if i do  `df.ix['Y', 'R']['snth'] = 12`, then all locations where i set an empty dict will look like `{'snth': 12}`

Comment: or, another way to look at it is that if you did applied `id` to the frame, all the empty dicts would have the same id

Comment: it doesn't really matter, though, if OP is never going to update the dicts

Comment: @acushner I see what you mean but this is a problem for the OP storing empty dicts, for me this is a wierd thing to do and is just going to open up a [world of pain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAPXGuRIXsA)

Comment: @acushner, you're right that this is exactly what happens with this solution.  While I don't plan to update the empty dicts right now, it IS a bug waiting to happen, and then a world of pain of course.  Also this would still require me to manually iterate through every column, correct?

Answer (score 0):

@Josh_Bode's answer helped me a lot. Here's a very slightly different version. I used mask() instead of where() (pretty trivial change). I also updated the way to assign an empty dictionary. By creating a list of dict instances as long as the frame and then assigning that, I avoided the trap of many copies of the same dict.

```
>>> data = {'Q': {'X': {2: 2010}, 'Y': {2: 2011, 3: 2009}}, 'R': {'X': {1: 2013}}}
>>> frame = DataFrame(data)
>>> frame
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}        NaN

>>> frame.mask(frame.isna(), lambda x: [{} for _ in range(len(frame)])
                    Q          R
X           {2: 2010}  {1: 2013}
Y  {2: 2011, 3: 2009}         {}
```